# Does using decision trees to predict risky alcohol consumption make sense?

Tags: classification, dataset

**Context:** I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis and have decided to focus on what factors that contribute to students that have risky alcohol habits at my university. I am planing on doing a big survey to gather data about the students habits.

**First Possible Approach:** Since the classification problem is alcohol consumption I am having a slight issue in phrasing the question and its options. A [similar study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/296695247_USING_DATA_MINING_TO_PREDICT_SECONDARY_SCHOOL_STUDENT_ALCOHOL_CONSUMPTION) worked with a [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/STUDENT+ALCOHOL+CONSUMPTION) based on educational data mining that used two measures `Daily=daily alcohol consumption` and `Weekly=weekly alcohol consumption`. The measures were `1 - very low` to `5 - very high`. Then they calculated the consumption as such:

```
(Weekly * 2 + Daily + 5) / 7
```

If the value was > 3 then he/she was classified as big drinker and if the value was < 3 he/she was not classified as a big drinker.

**Second Possible Approach:** However each year my university sends out a big survey to gather data about how much alcohol our students drink. They define a risky alcohol consumption as such:

> 1. If you drink less than once a month then you have a low risk.
> 2. If you drink 1-3 times a month then it means an increased risk.
> 3. If you drink 1 time a week or often then that means you're in the
>      risk zone.

**Problem:** What are you thoughts on the matter? I am not an data mining expert and that's why I am turning to you guys. Is it necessary for a binary classification as the similar study with a delicate matter as alcohol consumption? Or is perhaps 3-5 options as a measure more suitable?